# How to solve.. A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the above error.
i read a lot of articles but not gains.
What i have already tried
 Use Validaterequest = "false" at page directive

Made the follwing changes in the web.config

"

i have also encoded the value as  server.htmlencode.
But no gains.

I am using iis 7.5 and .net frame work 4.0.

What else should i do and what are the main reasons which can through this exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client can help you

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this question: [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

If that doesn't contain the information you need, you might consider posting some code snippets here.

Also - your changes to the web.config don't appear to be posted as you intended.